# how to verify view is scrollable in mobile application (Automation)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Anyone knows automation script to verify a view (homePage/Browse) is scrollable or not. i can use ScrollTo(id) which is at the bottom of the page. But it is not a correct method to do, as test case passes if that element present in 1st page

Comment: Which appium-java-client you are using as per knowledge ScrollTo() is no more in appium?

Answer (score 0):

Basically You cannot. You could try to cast the view to ScrollView class however any custom view can implement scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the last visible element as "YourText" But this is
just a workaround that needs to be customized for each page.

Here we are using swipe until we find the element. In this case, the last visible element indicates the margin of the page.

```
Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();
System.out.println("s="+scrollStart);
Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.getHeight(); i++) {
driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,2000);
if (driver.findElement(By.name("YourText")).size()>0) 
exit;
}
driver.findElement(By.name("YourText")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the coordinates of any particular element like button etc unique element.

Swipe using driver.swipe() to 100 or more pixels.

And get the coordinates of that element again and check whether x or y coordinates changed or not.

This will let you know whether it is a single page application or more to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no API to check the view is scrollable or not but if you still require this then you can do work around

```
@Test
    public void testVerticalScroll()
    {
        //Try to Scroll till the 15th row
        driver.scrollTo("List item:15");
        //Assert that the 1st row is not visible.
        Assert.assertFalse( driver.findElement(By.name("List item:01")).isDiaplyes())
        //Assert that the 15th row is not visible.
        Assert.assertTrue( driver.findElement(By.name("List item:15")).isDiaplyes())

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check it. You have to find a layer that you will target for example:

`MobileElement scrollableLayer= driver.findElementById("elementID");`

Then you will extract attribute value "scrollable" of that element like this:

`String scrollableState = scrollableLayer.getAttribute("scrollable");`

And then you can check if the String value is true or false.

`if (scrollableState.equals("true")){System.out.println("it's scrolable"); }else{System.out.println("it's not scrolable");}`

Or you can do whatever you want with it :)